# finding two factors with a correlation in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
    function phi(table) {
      return (table[3] * table[0] - table[2] * table[1]) /
      Math.sqrt((table[2] + table[3]) *
            (table[0] + table[1]) *
            (table[1] + table[3]) *
            (table[0] + table[2]));
    }
    function tableFor(event, journal) {
      let table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
      for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
        let entry = journal[i], index = 0;
        if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;
        if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
        table[index] += 1;
    
      }
      return table;
    }
    function test(JOURNAL){
      for (let entry of JOURNAL) {
        if (entry.events.includes("peanuts") && 
           !entry.events.includes("brushed teeth")) { 
             entry.events.push("peanut teeth");
           }
      }
      console.log(phi(tableFor("peanut teeth", JOURNAL)));
    }
    
    var JOURNAL = [
      {"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brussel sprouts","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","candy","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brussel sprouts","pudding","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["bread","beer","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","nachos","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brushed teeth","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lettuce","nachos","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","brushed teeth","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","reading","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","ice cream","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","nachos","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","ice cream","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","peanuts","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":true},
      {"events":["potatoes","ice cream","brushed teeth","computer","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","ice cream","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["peanuts","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","ice cream","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","ice cream","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","candy","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","nachos","brushed teeth","running","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","beer","work","dentist"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","pudding","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","reading","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","pudding","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","peanuts","work"],"squirrel":true},
      {"events":["pizza","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brushed teeth","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","beer","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","peanuts","candy","work"],"squirrel":true},
      {"events":["carrot","peanuts","brushed teeth","reading","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","peanuts","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","exercise","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","peanuts","brushed teeth","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","peanuts","brushed teeth","computer","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","brushed teeth","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["bread","candy","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["potatoes","nachos","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","exercise","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brussel sprouts","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["candy","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brussel sprouts","brushed teeth","computer","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","candy","television","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","pudding","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","ice cream","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["spaghetti","peanuts","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":true},
      {"events":["bread","beer","computer","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lettuce","peanuts","brushed teeth","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","brushed teeth","television","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["carrot","peanuts","reading","weekend"],"squirrel":true},
      {"events":["potatoes","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lasagna","ice cream","work","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","peanuts","brushed teeth","cycling","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["pizza","brushed teeth","running","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["lettuce","brushed teeth","work"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["bread","brushed teeth","television","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
      {"events":["cauliflower","peanuts","brushed teeth","weekend"],"squirrel":false}
    ];
    test(JOURNAL);
```

```
// This makes sure the data is exported in node.js —
// `require('./path/to/jaques_journal.js')` will get you the array.
if (typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports && (typeof window == "undefined" || window.exports != exports))
  module.exports = JOURNAL;
if (typeof global != "undefined" && !global.JOURNAL)
  global.JOURNAL = JOURNAL;
```

My question is why the result of console.log(phi(tableFor("peanut teeth", JOURNAL))); is 1? In the JOURNAL we don't have "peanut teeth" but why it returns 1?

Comment: you're adding "peanut teeth" in the for-loop before the console.log(phi(tableFor("peanut teeth", JOURNAL))); , so you end up with "peanut teeth" in the JOURNAL.

Comment: Yeah, the `test()` function is adding "peanut teeth" to an event's array if it contains "peanuts" AND "brushed teeth".  Take a screen break - I think you're suffering from a spot of 'code blindness'  :D

Comment: (Side note: lines of ```test()``` were top-level code prior to having a runnable snippet, I just wrapped them into a function so every "actual" code-line can still precede ```JOURNAL``` just like in the original post)